# One object in multiple sections when sorting with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, collectionview

I’ve just started using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController and I'm kind of stuck. I've a Book entity which has a category attribute of type String. The data is loaded into a collection view and grouped by sections based on this category. All’s working fine this way, but the problem is that a Book should be able to appear in multiple categories (and collection view sections). I could change the category’s type to an Array of String, but how would I do the sorting then?

```
let request = Book.fetchedRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Book>
let categorySort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Book.category)), ascending:true)
request.sortDescriptors = [categorySort]

do {
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Book.category)), cacheName: nil) 
try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError {
print(“Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)”)
}
```

Should I just give up on using NSFetchedResultsController or is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... a Book should be able to appear in multiple categories (and collection view sections).
>
> Should I just give up on using NSFetchedResultsController or is it possible to make this work?

What you describe cannot be achieved with a fetched results controller.
`NSFetchedResultsController` takes all fetched objects (which are possibly
filtered by a predicate), sorts them according to the sort descriptors, and
groups them according to the `sectionNameKeyPath` argument.

There is no way that a fetched results controller provides the same object
multiple times (in the same or in different sections).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem in keeping the category attribute as a string. Just change the way you approach the array of Books.

Make an array of categories like

```
var booksInCategories: [[Book]] = []
```

This variable will hold all the books in one category inside each array. Let's assume your array of books are called `books`.

```
var books: [Book] = []
```

Then put each book in each of the categories and add it to the `booksInCatogories` object. Lets assume you have all the categories as another array of strings.

```
var categories = ["Fiction", "Science", "Children", "Education"] // just an example
```

If there are n categories, then there would be n arrays of books in `booksInCatogories`.

```
for category in categories {
    var booksInCategory: [Book] = []
    for book in books {
        if book.category.range(of: category) != nil { // checks if category string contains particular category
            booksInCategory.append(book)
        }
    }
    if booksInCategory.count > 0 { // to exclude empty array if a category doesn't have any books under it
        booksInCategories.append(booksInCategory)
    }
}
```

You can now use booksInCategories array to display all the books which belong to each category under each section using each array in `booksInCategories`.